# How do I get rounded edges on a football shape in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, corners

It seems like it should be pretty easy to get rounded tips on this football shape, but I have been trying for an hour now with no luck.  I must be overlooking something.

This is the shape:
[image: This is the shape.]

This is a rounded edge, which I can not achieve:
[image: This is a rounded edge.]

Answer (score 11):

Inkscape 1.2.x has a Corners Live Path effect, which is quite similar to the Rounded Corners widget in Adobe Illustrator. It's a nice feature, and is non-destructive, which means you can go back and edit it, and you can remove/disable the effect without altering the original.

1. Select an object, and do *Path > Path Effects*, hit the + button to add a new Path Effect
2. When the dialog opens search for "corner", and choose it

[image]

3. Switch to the Edit Paths by Nodes tool <kbd>N</kbd>, click and drag to select the two pointed corners, then click and drag the corners to round them as you like.

Here's an example

[image]

**Note:** If you want to bake in the Live Path Effect, and turn it into a normal path, do *Path > Object to Path*- but you need to be aware this is destructive and you won't be able to edit the corners as a path effect any more.

**Another method** without any effects

1. Draw a flattened ellipse and do *Object to Path* using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
2. Select the Edit Paths by Nodes tool <kbd>N</kbd> and in the controls along the top, hit the button to Show Transform Handles

[image]

3. Click and drag around two opposing nodes, then hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click and drag to enlarge the shape horizontally, do the same vertically if required.

[image]

**And finally** although not useful for your specific use case, you can also draw rounded polygons directly by using the Stars & Polygons tool, just change the Rounded parameter

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I figured out a way the moment I asked this.  I used a rounded stroke and converted the stroke to a path.  So easy and obvious.  I'm not sure why that took so long.